# Static (read only) calendar displaying available dates in Material UI

Tags: datepicker, material-ui

Is there a way to implement a Static read only calendar displaying available dates like for the booking system when you review an apartment and its availability with [Material UI pickers](https://v4-0-0-alpha-12.material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#static-mode)?

I have tried to use StaticDatePicker:

```html
     <StaticDatePicker
        disablePast
        displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
        disabled
        openTo="date"
        value={value}
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
        pickerProps={{ readOnly: true }}
      />
```

However, it still allows picking some date from that calendar...I would like it to be display only, showing what dates are taken and what available

Something like this displaying available & prohibited dates while not allowing user to pick any date (readOnly) [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmYWF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the - shouldDisableDate handler to prohibit all dates except the allowed ones:
https://v4-0-0-alpha-12.material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker

Comment: Thanks :) That's true. I am about to use it, but still, it will allow user to pick some date from that calendar and I just want to display prohibited dates on the calendar and not allow to pick any of them. **I updated my question with example**